# Python3 unable to start due to <no Python frame>

Tags: python, pip, apt

I can't use python due to some files being missing. After I accidentally deleted some folders related to python, I can't do anything with it.

I've tried reinstalling it with apt, but it refuses to. Pip doesn't work. Here's what I get when I try to start python using the python3 command:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000007f90889040 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that I'm running Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit). Also, when I say that I can't do anything with python, I can't do ANYTHING. Not even apt can do with it. I've tried apt uninstall, reinstall, remove, and purge, but all of them have errors, including the same errors when I try to run python. Also, apt uninstall isn't a command? Also, -f and --force don't work.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall python?   I dunno your OS but yeah, sounds like while you deleting things, you removed something being pointed to.  If you install, it should relink and/or reinstall dependancies...

Comment: use force option (`-f`) with `apt install` to force re-install., or use `apt reinstall ...`.

Comment: Apt won't do anything with python.